# Как переместить cursot drawler?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, edittext, android-cursor

Есть 2 EditText. Курсор стоит на первом. Как переместь этот курсор на второй EditText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Программно можно сделать так:

```
view.requestFocus()
```

и дальше нужно будет установить слушатель нажатий кнопок на клавиатуре при фокусе на первом поле для ввода:

```
EditText te = ...
te.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event){
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
            view.requestFocus()
            return true; 
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

так же в xml можно добавить поля:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
android:imeOptions="actionNext"
android:singleLine="true"
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/.."
```

ключевым является:

```
android:nextFocusForward="@+id/.."
```

это означает что при нажатии кнопке next вы передадите фокус следующему view с id.

Comment: К сожалению код смогу проверить дня через 4-5, но мне кажется, что слушатель необязателен.

Comment: почему вы так считаете?в ответе два варианта идентичных между собой, один полностью программный а второй через xml :)

Comment: Я так считаю потому что мне нужно `view.requestFocus()` выполнять по нажатию кнопки на активити, а не на клавиатуре. `view.requestFocus()` отлично работает, спасибо)